# top: Is there a way to display the memory usage in percent and not in MB / GB

Tags: macos, terminal, memory

With `top` application, one can display the list of application sorted according to memory usage from highest so smallest with

```
top -o MEM
```

Is there a way to display the memory usage in percent and not in MB / GB?

For example, part of the output is the following:

```
PID  COMMAND  %CPU  MEM
401  firefox  10.1  675M
430  Finder   9.8   146M
```

With 16GB of RAM, I would assume that
675/16000=0.0421875 and 146/16000 = 0.009125. Therefore I would like to have something like this instead:

```
PID  COMMAND  %CPU  %MEM
401  firefox  10.1  4.2%
430  Finder   9.8   0.9%
```

Comment: What are you trying to analyse? Physical RAM usage is largely abstracted by virtual addressing, compression, etc.

Comment: Could you perhaps show us numbers. What are the absolute numbers shown and then what math you want to see “percentage of what” calculated? I agree it would be good to know the back story on what the end goal is to solve for.

Comment: thank you @bmike and benwiggy for your comments. I added an example in the question

Comment: So write a command that runs "top -o MEM" then parses and recalculates the values into the format you want, perhaps pipe and grep etc.

Comment: @SolarMike thank you for the comment. That's theoretically possible. But the question is: is there such a possibility with top out of the box?

Comment: I don't think so: but the question remains: what analysis are you trying to achieve? There may be another way of achieving your 'higher goal' -- e.g. monitoring a particular process's share of physical RAM.

Comment: Have you tried "man memory"?

Comment: @SolarMike. I just typed it and it refers to memory allocation used in C I think. But I am not sure how it could help solve the question. Can you be a bit more explicit?

Comment: @benwiggy: I assume that I have a fixed amout of RAM and would like to see what is the total RAM use and among this use, what is the percentage used by the different programs. Does that make sense?

Comment: Memory management is quite complex, and not just "filling a jug with water". The OS likes to use as MUCH RAM as possible. Top won't show file caching, for example, and memory compression means the 'real' memory usage is not necessarily a good indicator. What will you do with the info? Unless there's a problem, let the OS look after the memory, freeing you to do more interesting things.

Comment: @benwiggy thanks for the insight. Well I was thinking that when the computer is slow, or the fan gets noisy, inspect the memory usage and get rid of the hungry application. But maybe, looking at the CPU usage is better indicator to select which application to kill. What do yout think?

Comment: Yes, CPU usage is more likely to correlate to heat and fans. Slowness could be all sorts of things. It could be swapping to disk because of memory usage, but it could be other things.